# How to put this object behind everything else?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgflayers

Is it possible to put the rectangle with color gradient under everything else ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    yticklabel pos=left,grid=major,
    ]
    \fill[
        right color=white, 
        left color=white,
        middle color=blue!30, 
    ] (4.,-1) rectangle (6,6);
    \addplot [blue, domain=0:10] {.5*x+2};
    \addplot [red, dashed, domain=0:10] {x-3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With the TikZ library `backgrounds` you could do `\scoped[on background layer]\fill …;`. But maybe there's also a `pgfplots` solution …

Comment: Yeah, that works. Thanks but as I said I'll wait for some other solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
set layers,
yticklabel pos=left,grid=major,
]
\pgfonlayer{axis background}
\fill[right color=white, left color=white, middle color=blue!30] (4.,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) rectangle (6,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
\endpgfonlayer
\addplot [blue, domain=0:10] {.5*x+2};
\addplot [red, dashed, domain=0:10] {x-3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with blue shaded bar]

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how to stretch this from the automatic ```ymin```to ```ymax``` ? BTW this bar should replace the extra tick grid line from my previous (deleted) question

Comment: How do I set the centeral vertical line at some sepecific value x for it to work as a grid line ?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: In your previous question, the grid lines could easily have been draw with `\draw`. I was looking into conditional styling of the existing `extra x ticks`. I could not make it work easily. Her you can store a x value with `\newcommand{\xval}{5}` and use e.g. `({\xval-1}.,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) rectangle ({\xval+1},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});`

Comment: Perhaps in this post, I mean the bar as that special extra grid line, is the best alternative till now